# Bluescreen after sleep caused by asmthub3

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bsod, usb-3

Regularly my PC crashes (BSOD) after waking up from sleep.

My PC: Windows 10 Pro 64bit, ASUS Z170-A, i5-6600, 8GB RAM DDR4

The shown error event is: DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE

The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck. The bugcheck was: 0x0000009f (0x0000000000000003, 0xffffe001f86d0cd0, 0xfffff801b9d7b890, 0xffffe001f86e7ab0). A dump was saved in: C:\WINDOWS\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: f06fbd30-550c-40f5-ae3c-4299480d7ce9.

I loaded the memory.dmp with the tool WinDebug and it indicates the probable cause is asmthub3.sys.

This driver seems to be for the USB-3 hub integrated on my ASUS board.
Now I have updated several times different versions of this driver, but the problem remains. ASUS support is unable to help and ASmedia is not responding.

Has anyone seen anything similar or any suggestion on how to find a workaround to avoid the bluescreen, other than disabling sleep mode?

Kind regards

Jan

Comment: Windows includes since Windows 8 a generic USB3 driver. So uninstall the ASMEdia driver in device manager (also elete the driver files) and look if Windows detects the USB 3.0 chip and tries to install the generic USB 3.0 driver.

Comment: have you tried the default driver?

Comment: Thank you @magicandre1981, I am trying now with the default driver. It seems to work fine, but I want to try some more time.

Comment: Ok, with the windows 10 drivers it works perfectly. Thank you very much @magicandre1981. How can I mark your answer as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [Windows 8, Microsoft includes a generic USB 3.0 driver](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/b8/2011/08/22/building-robust-usb-3-0-support/), so there is no need to install 3rd party drivers (only if the generic driver doesn't support the chip like old Fresco Logic 1000 chips). So [go to device manager](http://ccm.net/faq/43223-open-the-device-manager-in-windows-10)

[image]

and uninstall the ASmedia devices

[image]

and install the default Windows drivers (shows up as (Microsoft) at the end)

[image]